# Passing Array in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to pass array in `AsyncTask`'s `publishProgress`?
In my code I have:

```
publishProgress(returnOK, dataType, data)
```

Where `data` would be an array (user decides how much data he would like to receive).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The type is generic, so it can be an array.  Just make sure both sides treat it as such.